# Axios.post mock function is not called with Jest, VueJS

Tags: vue.js, axios, jestjs, mocking

I want to test my action.

- My action has 1 AXIOS request and 1 mutation.
- I mocked my axios with jest.mock(“axios” …). I return a Promise.
- I defined a mock value with the method mockResolvedValue().

But when I test if my axios.post is called with the method toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1), Jest tells me 0 time.

My test:
[image]

My action:

[image]

My error:

[image]

Someone knows why my axios.post is not called ?

Comment: Please, post the code instead of images. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . You didn't do anything that could call it, so it wasn't called. And you're testing only your own test with other assertions instead of actual unit.

Comment: Sorry, I will not post any image for the code anymore. Thank you for let me know. I found the solution, I post the solution.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out, self-answers are welcome on SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution:

```js
    import actions from '@/store/actions'
    import mutations from '@/store/mutations'
    import state from '@/store/state'
    import store from '@/store'
    import axios from 'axios'
    
    let url = ''
    let body = {}
    
    jest.mock("axios", () => ({
      post: jest.fn((_url, _body) => { 
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
          url = _url
          body = _body
          resolve(true)
        })
      })
    }))
    
    //https://medium.com/techfides/a-beginner-friendly-guide-to-unit-testing-the-vue-js-application-28fc049d0c78
    //https://www.robinwieruch.de/axios-jest
    //https://lmiller1990.github.io/vue-testing-handbook/vuex-actions.html#testing-actions
    describe('getGameList', () => {
      test('Success: should return the game list of the user and update gameList in the store', async () => {
        const context= {
          state: {
            user: {
              id:1
            }
          },
          commit: jest.fn()
        }
        const response = {
          data: [ 
            { id:1, name:"game_name1" },
            { id:2, name:"game_name2" }
          ]
        };
    
        axios.post.mockResolvedValue(response) //OR axios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(response));
        await actions.getGameList(context)
        expect(axios.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith("api/game_list_of_user",{"user_id":1});
        expect(axios.post).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
        expect(context.commit).toHaveBeenCalledWith("UpdateGameList", response.data)
    
      });
    
      test('Error: an error occurred', () => {
        const errorMessage = 'Error';
        axios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
          Promise.reject(new Error(errorMessage))
        );
      });
    
    });
```